# How does MOSFET gate-drain capacitance behave?

Tags: mosfet

When a voltage is applied to MOSFET drain, Cgd acts as closed switch and for a short moment raises the gate voltage to drain voltage. Is this statement true?

In Falstad circuit simulator (see [simulation here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BOJyWoSATNALAdgMy4AcGGY2%20R%20GArHSNgGwg0uQsCmAtGGAFAAnTNnZdsRYe3LYoUaPwBmIHo1FhmK0QmYiQ%20aKzCQ%20Ac0xEJ085dWzjhNdhldtk5a4jtjAZ2U0n7hoUGIGyEAoAhgA23hx8AEp%20AS4aNLgarl4MUmAhWTA0fADuysGhXPiMEilQxcrUUhjVDXZ8EeABrowyrpYhPCFG8HCY0Ai4FN2Q1LwINN34ctjqjKtr62uLQ-CCbmKWyeKyGDtCVvsg3aUSUsN1VkdWXqaXzkdXFXm1Qhi6Vv8BdgnOB1X5aZhg661EoAmT-XK1ADGHRk7CuWTA3HQ5DGE0YYHGRAQRHmkAQeVgkH4MMBKKhxiEV3eqLCOxKV1cnxAHl2AwOzkhTwYuBBQgqVVk4uqmWFdwADntXPhIM4PK0AC6hTmc9TgZQQLgweC0NJpAiMfwWsD4NLKLDLKkkkhERgIES8bBYzAjAAmHEiAFcouq%20JquKQehoI-rmBADb9KZATbgzZV-Lg7dArWBcCK6KsiJAXV7gSA-YHgwk7bh%20rrwzX6bI-l8vAY6lLJS0gXwffqmnSuFcrIMAHLLcSh0ojaj1CUzqR2RPkIi4IwYG3r1fTcngX3%20iJBkMlMTT-oifLt8%20diXPY%20VG6zmy1Mwdo4dmXGdkyZnciH3AKPAEhbfHSBKDAEQrbMYiQduooj3uA-ZZM2dhyIUMEzio9Rng%207C6AMqEFLycExvqCJYbcxG2Fh4ZFqRlF3hKNQ8OkoSfthQJ0Z8Ui2Ayj7gNRCEnA%20UG8kJXFCfMrLGC%20kkaEJDbPIk-w7sOujIUCBiEW2jESMJHHejc7bRjqtiZKCFh0oKgJtAZ5zWTIfR9ruwytvAy5buuNCbkY%20A7jAvAWIFRDBcFWyuf%20jnsMBTx1DFyRDjZx4kdqzDmceGANjRkIUe2wE0Zhup8fWtZRg2Mp4CCGXlVGvy-kiMZqGV-Togw0Aiq5nVUl6AyJiITgWggcD4NgFJwPwYoIcxmUtSyRpUlRTWNfVtzFTOnKFcweEde260ZGlW18AA9noepSOkQ2sPNVJyO5xynfgx3gNiYTKra12eJSNBGN0CBgC68CqJleqDOgj2UCwIAAGKeE2Iw8CAADKR0BgIiIcAAOt4ABuR3BhEJhxEAA)), I added Cgd to simulate a real MOSFET and these short bursts of charging/discharging cause oscillation in the circuit.

Is this a real world issue or is it just the simulator?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9IB4F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Try putting ground on your circuit and explaining where the negative terminal of the voltage source was connected. Also try using a 1 milliohm resistor in series with the power supply to make it more like a real world scenario. Yes, Falsetad is unrealistic

Comment: @Andyaka It's not a circuit Andy, it's the model of MOSFET gate capacitance and it's all over google. I did added 1mΩ in series with the capacitor but it had no effect.

Comment: @Andyaka *ground on my circuit* where? the negative terminal of the voltage source IS connected to ground. BTW I meant no disrespect! in fact I have so much respect for you Andy.

Comment: Without a ground node on your circuit and, without knowing that the negative terminal of the power supply is grounded, the MOSFET gate will always be at the same potential as the drain and the source.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, the negative terminal of the power supply is grounded. now how do I fix this oscillation?

Comment: @ElectronSurf What was the voltage applied and what are the capacitances of  Cgd and Cgs?

Comment: Did you try reducing the timestep first? Setting it to 0.1µs gives offhand reasonable results. Never blame the simulator for modeling errors; blame the model first!

Comment: @TimWilliams So you don't think it would oscillate in real world?

Comment: @ElectronSurf You should include ALL the details of your simulation, including Vds, Cgs and screenshot(s) of the simulation. It is likely due to some detail you haven't told us that the simulation produces unrealistic results.

Comment: It might oscillate, but there are factors that real components exhibit that Falstad's models I doubt include, and many manufacturers might not even in their official SPICE models. The biggest potential issue is stray inductance in the layout. Capacitance direct to the gate terminal is generally unwise. But a bit of resistance in series (say 10 ohms or more) is likely enough to prevent that. Such oscillation is usually well over 30MHz, and can be 400MHz or more with modern transistors.

Comment: BTW, semi-meta to readers -- are these comments getting too answery? They aren't answering the body of the question as currently written, but may be answering the underlying problems. I would like to lead the OP towards a deeper and clearer question and it seems there are issues in this direction to be explored first. Then again, with answers already in place (including an accept), perhaps this post has run its course.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hey, thanks for the extra info. I ditched the class B amplifier, it was making it unstable. also a bit of hysteresis for the comparator helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unrealistic to me that the Cgd would bring Vgs up to the full drain voltage (Vds) applied, simply because Vgd and Vgs would form a capacitive divider and there would have to be at least **some** reduction in voltage on the gate compared to drain voltage. 
You didn't specify voltages, capacitances, any values in your simulation nor a screenshot so that we can better analyze your problem. I can only guess it has something to do with drain voltage being high, Cgd being large and maybe the Cgs being omitted.

The drain voltage influencing gate voltage through Cgd is realistic and possible if Cgd and Vd are large enough to charge the Cgs up to the Vgs threshold voltage and there is nothing loading or grounding the Vgs.

It is a real-world issue which can cause unwanted turn-ons, turn-offs and oscillations, and that's one of the reasons why there is at least a resistor between gate and source, and why it is recommended to have a low-impedance drive that brings the Vgs as low as possible and *keeps* it low when MOSFET is supposed to be off.

Even though Cgd is smaller than Cgs, the Vd typically being significantly higher than Vgs threshold voltage is what makes it more influential over Cgs, as you know from the formula Q=CV that a charge is a product of both capacitance and voltage applied, so even if Cgd is 10 times smaller than Cgs, a 10 times larger Vds than Vgs will give Cgd a charge equal to the charge on Cgs.

Let's assume 12V on drain, 0V on source. 
Let's also assume a 4V Vgs threshold. 
As the gate voltage rises from 0V to 4V, the capacitor Cgd discharges to about 8V. Vd will be 12V, Vg will be 4, meaning Vd is 8V more positive than Vg. 
When MOSFET starts conducting, Vd starts going towards 0V, but since it is 8V more positive and the Vg is therefore 8V more negative compared to Vd, it will pull the Vg towards 0V, thus turning the MOSFET off. 
In reality, Cgd is significantly smaller than Cgs, and any driver capable of turning a MOSFET on is also capable of overcoming this negative feedback and keeping the MOSFET on.
This interplay between Vg and Vd through Cgd in the real world can be seen in the gate voltage turn-on transition curve below:
[image]

(image linked from Analog Devices [page](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/isolated-gate-drivers-what-why-and-how.html): "Isolated Gate Drivers—What, Why, and How?")

You can see how the gate voltage rises until the MOSFET starts turning on, which drives the Vd down to Vs and which in turn takes away from the Vg by Cgd discharge, keeping the Vgs flat for a moment until Vd reaches Vs and then the Vg continues to rise further towards the gate driver's output voltage.

Answer (score 5):

Sharp voltage transitions at the drain *do* get coupled capacitively back to the gate (and vice versa!), so your statement is nearly correct. It would be better to say that a *change* in drain potential will cause a proportional *change* in gate potential. The amount by which the gate changes will only be some fraction of the change at the drain, but not the full amount. As Edin Fifić pointed out, this is due in large part to the capacitive divider formed by \$C_{DG}\$ and \$C_{GS}\$.

This is easy to show in a simulation, where I place a series of sharp transitions at the drain, and measure what happens at the gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5osOM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

---

This is just a guess, but I think Falstad tries to simulate using fixed time intervals, to produce "real time" state updates on screen. This is a simplification that can lead to overshoot, when things change too quickly, and which in the next iteration becomes overshoot in the opposite direction. You see oscillations that might not occur in a real circuit.

Spice and other systems don't do anything in real time, they have as long as they like to complete a transient analysis. Effectively time step is modulated as a function of rate of change of state, to mitigate such errors.

However, in real life, ringing is eminently possible, even likely, where MOSFETs are switched quickly, because there is always parasitic inductance combining with the transistor's capacitances. It gets worse in closed loops, where feedback can easily become positive due to these capacitances and inductances, leading to outright oscillation.

If I'm right about the reason why Falstad oscillates, then it seems ironic that Falstad's overshooting (which is akin to "momentum", something associated with inductance/mass), is *accidentally* mimicking inductance, and producing oscillation/ringing you might expect in real life (albeit exaggerated). In contrast, Spice can show you a nice stable system in theory, but which would ring or oscillate in reality, because it doesn't account for parasitic impedances present in a physical circuit (unless you include such elements in the model).

As a side note, it is very easy to make *any* simulator oscillate when using ideal elements, such as switches and ideal diodes or op-amps, because these elements introduce discontinuities in the time-varying sate of a system. An ideal switch can change state instantly, an ideal diode has a sharp kink in its I-V curve, neither of which can occur in real life. Consider this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwnO4h.png)</sup>

SW1 is a voltage-controlled switch, switching on when X rises above +2.5V, which brings X to 0V, which switches off SW1, and so on. I dare you to simulate it.

Comment: Interesting. Without knowing much about the simulators, my guess is that he may have specified a high drain voltage and zero time step which could produce the unrealistic effect. But he didn't give us the details as he should have, including values and screenshots, though his question is a good one. It may be that Cgs was omitted in his simulation.

Comment: Falstad don't have a real MOSFET model with parasitic capacitance etc, I added the Cgd manually. I like the practical answers of yours, thank you.